# why parameter binding not work in oder by or select statement?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i dont know whether i am asking the right question,but i am willing to test,how the query paramenter binding get works.I tested

```
string sql = select data from table where data_id =:dataId;
Session session = sessionFactory.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter(dateId,"23456");
```

The result looks

```
select data from table where date_id=23456;
```

got result.

but when i try to use it in select or order by,it's not working

```
    string sql = select :data from table order by :dateId
Session session = sessionFactory.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameterList("data",data.split(","));
query.setParameter("dateId",dateId);
```

lets consider

```
data="date_Id,data";
dateId="date_id";
```

its shows

repitation of column name up to the end of row in table

output

```
row 1) date_id data
row 2) date_id data
```

expected output

```
row 1) 234,ert
row 2) 456,jhk
```

can any one explain how its work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your second example won't compile since the string `sql` is defined after use, I'll just assume that's a copy and paste error.

Sql parameters do not quite work that way. The sql the second example is producing is probably something along the lines of

```
select 'date_Id','data' from table order by 'date_Id'
```

Which, if there are two rows in `table`, will get the output you are seeing. What you need to do is put your own sql string together:

```
string sql="select " + data + " from table order by " + dateId;
```

A word of warning: You need to be exceedingly careful when you do something like this. Perhaps have a white list of allowable column names that you check against, and filter out any strings that are not on the white list.

Comment: Hi @Matt ,thanks for the replay,i edited the question,to align the sql  declaration before it create a session,i solved this using string concatination,but i need to know why its not work for select or order by,please give a explanation or link to refer..